# ArgumentError: Invalid session type: :server_db (expected one of [:http, :bolt, :embedded])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create a node using Ruby on Rails and I'm following the steps from [here](https://gist.github.com/cheerfulstoic/3142ed2e15ad08ef6631).

Everything is fine until I execute

```
Asset.create(title: 'A predictive analysis of predictive analytics')
```

It gives me

```
ArgumentError: Invalid session type: :server_db (expected one of [:http, :bolt, :embedded])"
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Can you test by replacing the line `config.neo4j.session_type = :server_db` in your `config/development.rb` file by this one : `config.neo4j.session.type = :bolt`

Cheers

Comment: Actually, development.rb is present in config/environment/ folder. I replaced it with :bolt and now it says 

'NoMethodError: undefined method `signature' for 46:Fixnum'

Comment: can you share with us the content of your config file ?

Comment: http://textuploader.com/dkg6w! This is development.rb file. There's no file called config

Comment: I'd suggest replacing it with `http` instead of `bolt`.  To change to `bolt` you should also change the port (though currently the `bolt` driver is slower than the `http` driver and there is at least one known issue with it).  That episode script was created before version 8.0 of the `neo4j` gem.  I'll updated it, but there is also an Upgrade Guide that covers the differences between 7.x and 8.x: http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/8.1.x/UpgradeGuide.html

Comment: Also, http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/ is always the best place to go for the latest documentation on the Neo4j.rb gems